# Why is the number of filters in CNNs usually an even number?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution

When choosing a number of filters in convolutional neural network architectures, the number of filters is an even number. For example, these are the numbers of filters in convolutional layers in AlexNet:

```
conv1 - 96, 
conv2 - 256, 
conv3 - 384, 
conv4 - 384, 
conv5 - 256.
```

Is there any rationale behind the filter numbers being the even numbers?

Comment: They are powers of two, just convention.

Answer (score 1):

just by convention, they are usually the power of 2.

and just by convention, the kernel size is always odd.(to keep the padding on each size the same)

the kernel size is usually 1 or 3.

when the kernel size is 1, it's called NiN(network in network).

Comment: They're not necessarily powers of 2 as given in the example of AlexNet.

Comment: it's just by covention, but not a must. you can set the number of filters to be odd, but why bother?(additionally, if you look at VGG net, the number of filters is always doubling or halfing, so even numbers are more common)[vggnet](http://image107.360doc.com/DownloadImg/2017/06/2410/102635711_1.png)